# x11vnc not working on n900

Tags: vnc, n900

A few days ago i came across a article of controlling n900 on my PC with help of ultravnc(on pc) and x11vnc(on n900), i worked according to article and was going smooth, but after installing x11vnc i tried to launch the application...but x11vnc unable to start a black screen display and and application exits.

Any suggestions???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

open x terminal

set a password

```
sudo gainroot
x11vnc -storepasswd
```

start the server

```
x11vnc -forever -usepw
```